# Host name on terminal changes when I connect internet : why?

Tags: terminal

```
[acme@localhost ~]$ su
Password: 
[root@localhost acme]#
```

Now I connect internet and  I get the following:

```
[root@localhost acme]# exit
exit
[root@localhost acme]# su
[root@dhcppc9 acme]#
```

**Edit**

```
[root@dhcppc9 lin64]# echo $PS1
[\u@\h \W]\$
```

**I observed that it is hapnning in user also not just when I am in superuser.**

Why this dhcppc9 is coming ?

OS: RHEL 6

Comment: in bash, the environment variable `PS1` define your bash prompt, could give us the result of `echo $PS1` ? to do so please [edit] your question instead of comment.

Comment: Short nickpitting: `PS1` is not an environment variable, but a shell variable. (It is used by the shell itself, rather than by commands called from that shell, you don't use export to set it and `env` will not list it.)

Comment: @michas thank you for the info, I didn't notice the difference.

Comment: when i enter /etc/dhcp in terminal , i could not find a file by the name dhclient.conf whereas dhclient.d is present in dhcp

Comment: @michas: when i enter /etc/dhcp in terminal , i could not find a file by the name dhclient.conf whereas dhclient.d is present in dhcp

Answer (score 2):

The DHCP Server in your network is configured to send a hostname via the dhcp handshake.

You can configure your client not to request a hostname. In the file `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` you can see how your dhcp client is configured.

Edit the `request` statement and remove the `host-name` out of the list. In my case, before:

```
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
        dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
```

and after:

```
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
        dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
```

Now your system should not change the hostname after connecting.

Comment: when i enter /etc/dhcp in terminal , i could not find a file by the name dhclient.conf whereas dhclient.d is present in dhcp. I using RHEL 6.0 , 64 bit

Comment: You can create that file with the content above, `dhclient` uses it if it exists.