# How to configure DHCP so that hostname is not sent?

Tags: rhel, dhcp

A simialr question [Host name on terminal changes when I connect internet : why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111829/host-name-on-terminal-changes-when-i-connect-internet-why) But since it was not resolved in my case so I am putting it here and asking in a different way.

The answer given [here by chaos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111829/host-name-on-terminal-changes-when-i-connect-internet-why/111832#111832) did not help me as I could not find the file mentioned in RHEL 6.0 64 bit `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

The content of the file:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

is

```
DEVICE="eth0"
HWADDR=70:54:D2:22:FA:A6
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="no"
```

. I can see there is no `DHCP_HOSTNAME`. But Still I am seeing a strange issue here. And the issue is that when I am not connected to internet:

```
[acme@localhost ~]$
```

But when I connect to internet:

```
 [acme@dhcppc9 ~]$
```

Why it is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Your dhcp client is getting an answer from your dhcp server with a hostname for your computer and it's your dhcp client that is changing your hostname. Try looking at the options of your client (dhclient or dhcpcd).