# My Linux server forgets its host name every day

Tags: linux, network-interface, hostname, hosts

I have a Linux server

```
# uname -a
Linux site 3.12.39-47-default #1 SMP Thu Mar 26 13:21:16 
UTC 2015 (a901594) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: SUSE LINUX
Description:    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12
Release:        12
Codename:       12
```

I had to change network settings. I've set one interface as DHCP in Gnome GUI. Since that moment I have a new problem: my server forgets its own host name every day. Its host name is "site", but when I check

```
#hostname
host
```

Then I set

```
#hostname site
```

Then check

```
#hostname
site
```

However, about in day later I check again

```
#hostname
host
```

Why does it happen?

/etc/hostname file contains:
  `site`

/etc/hosts file contains:

```
127.0.0.1           localhost
127.0.1.1           site
```

Comment: Is this VPS? This tends to happen with VPS servers.. that is why i made cron with @reboot to set hostname automatically at every startup.

Comment: @Luka, No, it is a physical server in the office LAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DHCP client can be configured to override the hostname given to the machine by the DHCP server. Depending on what DHCP client you use, this may be done differently.

`dhclient` may be configured with

```
supersede host-name "site";
```

in `/etc/dhclient.conf`, for example.

---

Unless you have very special requirements, I'd suggest you make the entry in `/etc/hosts` as

```
127.0.0.1 localhost site
```

This says "*`localhost` has IP address 127.0.0.1 and `site` is an alias for it*".

Comment: A better answer I suspect would be to address what the questioner said about having just turned on a DHCP client on the machine.  Because what is in those files is not the focus if [the DHCP client is configured as I suspect it is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111981/).

Comment: @JdeBP I missed that detail. Yes, you are correct. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda `127.0.0.1 localhost site` does not help me

Comment: @JdeBP  It's very similar to true. I've found checkbox "To recieve host name by DHCP" (not word for word - the server has translitted GUI) in Gnome GUI, and it was pressed.